# Обновить Adapter

Tags: android, adapter

Есть адаптер для RecyclerView. При нажатии элемент, открывается второе активити, при чем первое не закрывается (Нету finish()). Как только пользователь наигрался во второе активити, он нажимает назад, и попадает снова на RecyclerView. После этого на том элементе, на который нажимал пользователь должны появиться галочка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Галочку я добавляю в методе onBindViewHolder (в реализации адаптера). В таком случае галочка появляется только тогда, когда пользователь отматает далеко и вернется обратно (система забывает и отрисовывает вновь данный элемент). Как сделать так, чтобы при возвращении со второго активити галочка сразу же появилась без нужды в проматывании и возвращении?

Я придумал КОЛХОЗНОЕ решение которое мне не подходит. В методе onResume() класса, в котором лежит адаптер, поставил принудительную очистку и перезаполнение адаптера, что заставляет систему перерисовать и галочка появляется. Я полагаю, что это решается каким то методом, но не знаю каким. Спасибо

Comment: После обновления данных нужно выполнить notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: только не надо дергать все поля через notifyDataSetChanged. Достаточно только одно поле rw.adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ в коментарии!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете объект вроде такого:

```
class ListItem {

    private boolean isChecked;
    private YourRecyclerObject data;

    // setters and getters
}
```

Создаете список этих объектов где-то за пределами вашего адаптера (`Presenter/ViewModel` и т.п. сущности). Передаете этот список в ваше адаптер и в зависимости от поля `isChecked` проставляете галку.

При нажатии на элемент меняете значение этого параметра в вашем `Presenter/ViewModel` в списке и снова вызываете обновление адаптера с новым параметром. Можно вызывать и в другом месте если у вас галка должна появиться не сразу после клика, но суть все равно такая же должна быть. Так ваш адаптер будет тупой и не зависеть от внешних факторов, а настройки элементов вы сможете контролировать извне.

Чтоб не обновлять всякий раз весь список вместо вызова `notifyDataSetChanged()` вызывайте или `notifyItemChanged(position)`. Или еще лучше используйте [DiffUtils](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/504-primer-ispolzovanija-android-diffutil.html)